# how HADOOP_HOME refers hadoop command

Tags: linux, hadoop, bigdata

I'm completely new to hadoop framework and for the past few months I've been using linux . After I installing hadoop to /usr/local directory. I tried to run hadoop command in CLI and it responds as *hadoop command not found*, then I figured out environment variables aren't set, so I set the environment variables by the following commands

**export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/** 
**export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/**

It worked. Also I know what is an environment variable but my doubt is *how does the **Shell refers hadoop command** by using the **HADOOP_HOME** variable*

Comment: Duplicate. http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Answer (score 0):

`HADOOP_HOME` does nothing for when you type the `hadoop` command. (Or anything else in `$HADOOP_HOME/bin`, for that matter).

The `$PATH` where all the commands you type into the terminal are looked for.

Just `echo $PATH` and you'll see all the folders.

---

`HADOOP_HOME` is looked for by the hadoop components themselves, and isn't Linux specific.

Answer (score 0):

HADOOP_HOME variable is used by shell files like yarn-config.sh, mapred-config.sh that is why it is required for setting HADOOP_HOME variable so that when config files access it they can reach to main hadoop folder.

If you do not want to define HADOOP_HOME then you need to edit config script files by replacing HAOOP_HOME with the required directory address